# Is ediscovery deprecated in office 365?

Tags: ediscovery

I am trying to find eDiscovery center in office 365, I have a documentation and I am not sure if this is up to date or not? is there any new documentation about it? Is it discontinued or still used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eDiscovery center is very much alive. Two months ago the [Office 365 Complicance Center](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn876574.aspx) was updated on TechNet, and it may be that you are looking at an older article. However the interface is changing, but the features will stay the same or improve.

> The Office 365 Compliance Center contains the key compliance-related features for an Office 365 admin to manage compliance across Office 365, Exchange Online, and SharePoint Online. This new management interface represents our evolving compliance offering, which will eventually span all Office 365 compliance-related features and help you meet your legal, regulatory, and organizational compliance requirements. Consolidating compliance functionality across services into this single area will make compliance features easier to access and enhance your end-to-end task-based experience.

[image]

See the article [eDiscovery in the Office 365 Compliance Center](https://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms.o365.cc.ediscoveryhelp.aspx).

> Use the eDiscovery cases page in the Office 365 Compliance Center to access and manage eDiscovery cases in the eDiscovery Center of your SharePoint Online organization. Using the Compliance Center is quick and easy way to go to the eDiscovery Center, manage existing eDiscovery cases, create new eDiscovery cases, and close eDiscovery cases that are no longer needed.

## Note

> To access the eDiscovery cases page in the Compliance Center, you have to be a member of the eDiscovery Manager role group in the Compliance Center. For more information about permissions, see [Permissions in the Office 365 Compliance Center](https://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms.o365.cc.adminrolegroups.aspx).

Comment: thanks benny, why is it used? is it different from delve? I can't really see the usage of it? will documents be read only in sharepoint sites when ediscovery works? +1 for your detailed answer, much appreciated.

Comment: @EdDon eDiscovery is udde to get the published version at a specific point in time. Even if current version is 11 a year ago it might have been 7. In eDiscovery you define a point in time and get all defined documents at that time. Very useful in compliance!